# Placeholder in Scala function doesnt work with mutable Maps

Tags: scala, function, function-literal

I have the following code in Scala which works:

```
var queryMap = Map("name" -> "tim")
age_list.foreach { age => queryMap += ("age" -> age.toString) }
```

If I include placeholders in the function, it breaks:

```
var queryMap = Map("name" -> "tim")
age_list.foreach { queryMap += ("age" -> _.toString) }
```

The following error is thrown:

```
value += is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]
```

queryMap becomes an immutable Map instead of a mutable Map. Is there something wrong with my syntax structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

_ I cannot reproduce this error, I get a different one:

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>) => "age".$minus$greater(x$1.toString))
```

Which means that the underscore is not bound to the `foreach`, but to after the `+=`. Underscores are bound inside parentheses, if there are any. Hence you can remove them and it will work.

```
var queryMap = Map("name" -> "tim")
age_list.foreach { queryMap += "age" -> _.toString }
```

Comment: brilliant. I didn't realize it was tagged to the parentheses